# NullPointException ao settar valor vindo de Converter

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, nullpointerexception

Tenho uma aplicação onde preciso calcular dados vindos de um determinado relacionamento.

Quando `usuarioController.view == 3`, define-se um `Login` para `Usuario` e um `Plano` (já persistido) para `Login` para que na próxima etapa o `UsuarioController` calcule a soma do preço de todos os planos contido em todos os logins, porém o `Login` não está populado com o `Plano`.
Será esse um problema no Converter?

Usuario

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "rg"))
public class Usuario implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 150)
@Pattern(regexp = "[^0-9]*", message = "Não deve conter números")
private String nome;


@NotNull
private String rg;

private String cpf;

private String cnpj;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dataNascimento;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Contato contato;


@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Endereco endereco;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "usuario_id") 
private List<Login> login = new ArrayList<Login>();

@Enumerated
private Pessoa pessoa;

@Enumerated
private TipoCadastro tipoCadastro;


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "usuario_id") 
private List<Cobranca> cobranca;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getRg() {
    return rg;
}

public void setRg(String rg) {
    this.rg = rg;
}

public String getCpf() {
    return cpf;
}

public void setCpf(String cpf) {
    this.cpf = cpf;
}

public String getCnpj() {
    return cnpj;
}

public void setCnpj(String cnpj) {
    this.cnpj = cnpj;
}

public Contato getContato() {
    return contato;
}

public void setContato(Contato contato) {
    this.contato = contato;
}

public Endereco getEndereco() {
    return endereco;
}

public void setEndereco(Endereco endereco) {
    this.endereco = endereco;
}

public List<Login> getLogin() {

    return login;
}

public void setLogin(List<Login> login) {
    this.login = login;
}

public void addLogin(Login login){
    this.login.add(login);
    System.out.println("Numero de logins: " + getLogin().size());
}

public void addLogin(){
    addLogin(new Login());
}


public Pessoa getPessoa() {
    return pessoa;
}

public void setPessoa(Pessoa pessoa) {
    this.pessoa = pessoa;
}

public TipoCadastro getTipoCadastro() {
    return tipoCadastro;
}

public void setTipoCadastro(TipoCadastro tipoCadastro) {
    this.tipoCadastro = tipoCadastro;
}

public Date getDataNascimento() {
    return dataNascimento;
}

public void setDataNascimento(Date dataNascimento) {
    this.dataNascimento = dataNascimento;
}

public List<Cobranca> getCobranca() {
    return cobranca;
}

public void setCobranca(List<Cobranca> cobranca) {
    this.cobranca = cobranca;
}

public void addCobranca(Cobranca cobranca){
    if(this.cobranca == null)
        this.cobranca = new ArrayList<Cobranca>();
    this.cobranca.add(cobranca);
}
public void addCobranca(){
    addCobranca(new Cobranca());
}
```

Login

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@Dependent
public class Login implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
private Usuario usuario;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

private Plano plano;

private String user;
private String pass;
private String mac;


public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public Usuario getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}
public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}
public String getUser() {
    return user;
}
public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
}
public String getPass() {
    return pass;
}
public void setPass(String pass) {
    this.pass = pass;
}

public Plano getPlano() {
    return plano;
}
public void setPlano(Plano plano) {
    System.out.println("Setando plano " + plano.getNome());
    this.plano = plano;
}
public String getMac() {
    return mac;
}
public void setMac(String mac) {
    this.mac = mac;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Login [id=" + id + ", usuario=" + usuario + ", plano=" + plano
            + ", user=" + user + ", pass=" + pass + "]";
}
}
```

UsuarioController

```
@Model
@SessionScoped
public class UsuarioController implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject
private FacesContext facesContext;

@Inject
private UsuarioRegistration usuarioRegistration;

@Produces
@Named
private Usuario novoUsuario;

private Integer view = 1;


@PostConstruct
public void initNovoUsuario(){
    novoUsuario = new Usuario();
    novoUsuario.setEndereco(new Endereco());
    novoUsuario.setContato(new Contato());

}

public void register() throws Exception{
    try{
        usuarioRegistration.register(novoUsuario);
        FacesMessage m = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Registred!", "Registration successful");
        facesContext.addMessage(null, m);
        initNovoUsuario();
    } catch (Exception e){
        String errorMessage = getRootErrorMessage(e);
        FacesMessage m = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, errorMessage, "Registration unsuccessful");
        facesContext.addMessage(null, m);
    }
}

private String getRootErrorMessage(Exception e){
    String errorMessage = "Registration falied. See server log for more information";
    if (e == null)
        return errorMessage;

    Throwable t = e;
    while (t != null){
        errorMessage = t.getLocalizedMessage();
        t = t.getCause();
    }
    return errorMessage;
}

public List<Pessoa> getPessoa(){
    return Arrays.asList(Pessoa.values());
}

public List<UF> getUf(){
    return Arrays.asList(UF.values());
}

public List<TipoCadastro> getTipoCadastro(){
    return Arrays.asList(TipoCadastro.values());
}

public Integer getView() {
    return view;
}

public void setView(Integer view) {
    this.view = view;
}
public void proximoView(){
    view++;
}

public void anteriorView(){
    view--;
}

public void removeLogin(Login login){
    if(novoUsuario.getLogin().contains(login))
        novoUsuario.getLogin().remove(login);
}

public void removeCobranca(Cobranca cobranca){
    if(novoUsuario.getCobranca().contains(cobranca))
        novoUsuario.getCobranca().remove(cobranca);
}

public void addCobranca(){
    Double d = 0.0;
    for(Login l : novoUsuario.getLogin())
        d += l.getPlano().getValor();

    novoUsuario.addCobranca(new Cobranca("Mensalidade" , d));

}
```

PlanoConverter

```
@FacesConverter(value = "planoConverter", forClass = Plano.class)
@Named
public class PlanoConverter implements Converter {



@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String string) {
    if (string != null && !string.isEmpty()) {
        return (Plano) uic.getAttributes().get(string);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object o) {
    if (o != null && (o instanceof Plano)) {
        return String.valueOf(((Plano) o).getId());
    }

    return null;
}    
}
```

novoUsuario.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="WEB-INF/templates/default/main.xhtml">
<ui:define name="content">
  <h1 class="page-header "> <i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i> Cliente</h1>
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
     <li><a href="#">Cliente</a></li>
     <li class="active">Novo Cliente</li>
  </ol>
  <h:form >
  <b:panel rendered="#{usuarioController.view == 1}">

        <h2>Cadastro de Clientes</h2>
        <p>Enforces annotation-based constraints defined on the
           model class.
        </p>
        <b:messages styleClass="messages"
           errorClass="invalid" infoClass="valid"
           warnClass="warning" globalOnly="true"/>
        <h:panelGrid columns="3" columnClasses="titleCell">
           <h:outputLabel for="nome" value="Tipo de Cadastro: " />
           <b:selectOneMenu id="pessoa" value="#{novoUsuario.pessoa}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{usuarioController.pessoa}" var="pessoa" itemLabel="#{pessoa.descricao}" itemValue="#{pessoa}"/>
            </b:selectOneMenu>
           <h:message for="nome" errorClass="invalid" />

        </h:panelGrid>
        <p>
           <h:panelGrid columns="2">

           </h:panelGrid>
        </p>

  </b:panel>


  <b:panel rendered="#{usuarioController.view == 2}">
              <h2>Cadastro de #{novoUsuario.pessoa.descricao}</h2>
        <p>Enforces annotation-based constraints defined on the
           model class.
        </p>
        <b:messages styleClass="messages"
           errorClass="invalid" infoClass="valid"
           warnClass="warning" globalOnly="true"/>

   <h:panelGroup rendered="#{novoUsuario.pessoa eq 'FISICA'}">

        <h:panelGrid columns="3" columnClasses="titleCell">

            <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Name:" />
            <b:inputText id="name" value="#{novoUsuario.nome}" />
            <h:message for="name" errorClass="invalid" />

            <h:outputLabel for="rg" value="Rg:" />
            <b:inputText id="rg" value="#{novoUsuario.rg}" styleClass="rg" />
            <h:message for="rg" errorClass="invalid" />

            <h:outputLabel for="cpf" value="CPF:" />
            <b:inputText id="cpf" value="#{novoUsuario.cpf}" />
            <h:message for="cpf" errorClass="invalid" />

            <h:outputLabel for="tel1" value="Telefone:" />
            <b:inputText id="tel1" value="#{novoUsuario.contato.telefone}" />
            <h:message for="tel1" errorClass="invalid" />

            <h:outputLabel for="tel2" value="Telefone Trabalho:"  />
            <b:inputText id="tel2" value="#{novoUsuario.contato.telefoneD}" />
            <h:message for="tel2" errorClass="invalid" />

            <h:outputLabel for="celular" value="Celular:" />
            <b:inputText id="celular" value="#{novoUsuario.contato.celular}" />
            <h:message for="celular" errorClass="invalid" />

            <h:outputLabel for="email" value="Email:" />
            <b:inputText id="email" value="#{novoUsuario.contato.email}" />
            <h:message for="email" errorClass="invalid" />

            <h:outputLabel for="responsavel" value="Responsavel: " />
            <b:inputText id="responsavel" value="#{novoUsuario.contato.responsavel}" />
            <h:message for="responsavel" errorClass="invalid" />

            <h:outputLabel for="uf" value="Estado: " />
            <b:selectOneMenu id="uf" value="#{novoUsuario.endereco.uf}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{usuarioController.uf}" var="uf" itemLabel="#{uf.descricao}" itemValue="#{uf}"/>
            </b:selectOneMenu>
            <h:message for="uf" errorClass="invalid" />

            <h:outputLabel for="cidade" value="Cidade: " />
            <b:inputText id="cidade" value="#{novoUsuario.endereco.cidade}" />
            <h:message for="cidade" errorClass="invalid" />

            <h:outputLabel for="cep" value="CEP: " />
            <b:inputText id="cep" value="#{novoUsuario.endereco.cep}" />
            <h:message for="cep" errorClass="invalid" />

            <h:outputLabel for="bairro" value="Bairro: " />
            <b:inputText id="bairro" value="#{novoUsuario.endereco.bairro}" />
            <h:message for="bairro" errorClass="invalid" />

            <h:outputLabel for="logadouro" value="Rua: " />
            <b:inputText id="logadouro" value="#{novoUsuario.endereco.logadouro}" />
            <h:message for="logadouro" errorClass="invalid" />

            <h:outputLabel for="numero" value="Numero: " />
            <b:inputText id="numero" value="#{novoUsuario.endereco.numero}" />
            <h:message for="numero" errorClass="invalid" />

            <h:outputLabel for="complemento" value="Complemento: " />
            <b:inputText id="complemento" value="#{novoUsuario.endereco.complemento}" />
            <h:message for="complemento" errorClass="invalid" />

            <h:outputLabel for="tipoCadastro" value="Função: " />
            <b:selectOneMenu id="tipoCadastro" value="#{novoUsuario.tipoCadastro}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{usuarioController.tipoCadastro}" var="c" itemLabel="#{c.descricao}" itemValue="#{c}"/>
            </b:selectOneMenu>
            <h:message for="tipoCadastro" errorClass="invalid" />


        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:panelGroup> 
  </b:panel>


  <b:panel rendered="#{usuarioController.view == 3}">

        <h2>Internet</h2>
        <p>Enforces annotation-based constraints defined on the
           model class.
        </p>
        <b:messages styleClass="messages"
           errorClass="invalid" infoClass="valid"
           warnClass="warning" globalOnly="true"/>
        <h:panelGrid columns="3" columnClasses="titleCell">


           <h:dataTable id="tabelaLogin" value="#{novoUsuario.login}" var="l"
                    styleClass="table table-striped table-bordered">

            <h:column>
                <!-- column header -->
                <f:facet name="header">Usuário</f:facet>
                <!-- row record -->
                <b:inputText id="user" value="#{l.user}" />
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Senha</f:facet>
                <b:inputText id="pass" value="#{l.pass}" />
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">MAC</f:facet>
                <b:inputText id="mac" value="#{l.mac}" />
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Plano</f:facet>
                <p:selectOneMenu id="plano" value="#{l.plano}" converter="planoConverter">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{planoController.findAll()}" var="plano" itemLabel="#{plano.nome}" itemValue="#{plano}"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">#</f:facet>
                <b:commandButton action="#{usuarioController.removeLogin(l)}" value="Apagar" look="danger" />
            </h:column>

        </h:dataTable>



        </h:panelGrid>


  </b:panel>

  <b:panel rendered="#{usuarioController.view == 4}">

        <h2>Cobrança</h2>
        <p>Enforces annotation-based constraints defined on the
           model class.
        </p>
        <b:messages styleClass="messages"
           errorClass="invalid" infoClass="valid"
           warnClass="warning" globalOnly="true"/>
        <h:panelGrid columns="3" columnClasses="titleCell">


           <h:dataTable id="tabelaCobranca" value="#{novoUsuario.cobranca}" var="f"
                    styleClass="table table-striped table-bordered">

            <h:column>
                <!-- column header -->
                <f:facet name="header">ID</f:facet>
                <!-- row record -->
                <b:inputText id="id" value="#{f.id}" />
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Descrição</f:facet>
                <b:inputText id="descricao" value="#{f.descricao}" />
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Valor</f:facet>
                <b:inputText id="valor" value="#{f.valor}" />
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Vencimento</f:facet>
                <b:inputText id="vencimento" value="#{f.vencimento}" />
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Enviar Cobrança</f:facet>
                <h:selectOneRadio value="#{f.enviarCobranca}"></h:selectOneRadio>
            </h:column>

            <h:column >
                <f:facet name="header">#</f:facet>
                <b:commandButton action="#{usuarioController.removeCobranca(f)}" value="Apagar" look="danger" />
            </h:column>

        </h:dataTable>



        </h:panelGrid>


  </b:panel>

  <b:commandButton id="anterior" action="#{usuarioController.anteriorView()}" value="Anterior" look="warning"/>
  <b:commandButton value="Add Login" actionListener="#{novoUsuario.addLogin()}"  update="tabelaLogin" look="success" rendered="#{usuarioController.view == 3}"/>
  <b:commandButton value="Add Cobrança" actionListener="#{usuarioController.addCobranca()}"  update="tabelaCobranca" look="success" rendered="#{usuarioController.view == 4}"/>
  <b:commandButton id="proxima" action="#{usuarioController.proximoView()}" value="Próximo" look="primary"/>
  </h:form>
```

Erro

```
1:38:07,985 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/AuthNET].[FacesServlet]] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-3) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet FacesServlet threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.authnet.model.Login.setPlano(Login.java:67) [classes:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.setValue(BeanELResolver.java:383) [jboss-el-api_2.2_spec-1.0.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.Final-redhat-1]
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._setValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:255) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.setValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:281) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.setValue(AstValue.java:199) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.setValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:257) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.setValue(WeldValueExpression.java:64) [weld-core-1.1.23.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.23.Final-redhat-1]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:131) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:822) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processUpdates(UIInput.java:739) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.component.UIData.iterate(UIData.java:2013) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.component.UIData.processUpdates(UIData.java:1266) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processUpdates(UIForm.java:281) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1244) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processUpdates(UIViewRoot.java:1223) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.UpdateModelValuesPhase.execute(UpdateModelValuesPhase.java:78) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema trocando o Converter

```
@FacesConverter(value = "planoConverter", forClass = Plano.class)
@Named
public class PlanoConverter implements Converter {
    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, String value) {
        if (value != null && !value.isEmpty()) {
            return (Plano) uiComponent.getAttributes().get(value);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, Object value) {

        if (value instanceof Plano) {
            Plano plano = (Plano) value;
            if (plano != null && plano instanceof Plano && plano.getId() != null) {
                uiComponent.getAttributes().put( plano.getId().toString(), plano);
                return plano.getId().toString();
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Poderia explicar o que mudou e como o script esta funcionando agora? Isto pode ser útil pra outros usuários.